# Adding a UIBarButtomItem but it does not showup on interface

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to add a go back button to the viewController programatically however it does not show up on the interface via simulator.  I am missing something in my code??  There are build errors just a blank screen!

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void) performAdd:(id)paramSender{
   NSLog(@"Button got called");
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.title =@"go Back";

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
     initWithBarButtonSystemItem:(UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd)
     target:self
     action:@selector(performAdd:)];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@end
```

Comment: Are you using a Storyboard? If so you need to embed it in a UINavigationController first

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I ended up going a different direction before I saw your answer. The reason for this exercise was to get control over the button as I was having difficulties hiding it.